# Turn off Compatibility Mode inside of Page Viewer Web Part (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: java, sharepoint, web-parts

We have web site that we created that uses java in it for sorting tables. When I go directly to the page it works find (I had to turn of compatibility mode for the site). But when I take this site and try to put it in a Page Viewer Web Part it breaks and does not show all the java. How do I turn off compatibility mode inside of the Page Viewer Web Part?

P.S. It works fine in Chrome. I just have this issue in IE.